# How can I link to a result in the COCA corpus?

Tags: discussion

I want to respond to the question *[Is it common to use “perverted” as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256286/is-it-common-to-use-pervert-as-in-a-pervert-as-an-adjective)* with evidence from the [COCA Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).

But I don't want to link to the generic COCA main page or landing page, I want to link to particular results.  Ideally, I'd like to provide a link so the OP could see a page like this, with all 3 panels:

[image: COCA corpus screenshot, marked up]

But I'd settle if I could link to just one of the panels; for preference, the main panel, outlined in yellow in the bottom-right, which lists all the examples of *perverted* used as an adjective, but I'd also accept the panel giving measurements of relative usage, outlined in orange in the top-right.

The problem is I'm stymied by the site's use of iFrames.  I was able to sniff the HTTP traffic and get the appropriate query string to, theoretically, produce the content of either the examples panel:

`http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=perverted.[j*]&r=`

or, again theoretically, the content of the usage metrics panel:

`http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x2.asp?chooser=seq&p=perverted.%5Bj%5D&w2=&wl=4&wr=4&r1=&r2=&ipos1=-select-&B7=SEARCH&sec1=0&sec2=0&sortBy=freq&sortByDo2=freq&minfreq1=freq&freq1=10&freq2=10&numhits=100&kh=100&groupBy=words&whatshow=raw&saveList=no&changed=&corpus=coca&word=&sbs=&sbs1=&sbsreg1=&sbsr=&sbsgroup=&redidID=&ownsearch=y&compared=&holder=&whatdo=seq&waited=n&rand1=y&whatdo1=1&didRandom=n&minFreq=freq&s1=0&s2=0&s3=0&perc=mi`

But plugging these URLs directly into a browser tab simply produces an error. I'm guessing the webapp is sensitive to referrer URLs or session cookies or something.

Does anyone know how I can create a link which would take visitors directly to the results of a particular COCA query?  If not, do you know of a more-easily-citable corpus of comparable scope and reputation?

Or, if not, would this be a legitimate question for [Webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79824/how-can-i-link-to-a-result-in-the-coca-corpus)?

Comment: They used to have a convenient link to all your queries in your personal history. And probably elsewhere. I know I've used it before on more than one occasion. Lemme see...

Comment: Does [this](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x1.asp?c=coca&q=36262893) work for you?

Comment: Haha, nevermind, it doesn't even work for *me*. I only get one frame. Well, file a bug with them or wait it out.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, that *almost* worked. I got the search panel frame, and a popup for the actual results. But given the prevalence of popup blockers (which initially made it seem like the link didn't work for me), I'd prefer something that linked directly to the results, or users might get confused. But it's definitely a step in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I didn't get the results myself. Apparently my browser blocks the popup, with no warning or anything, and I never even installed any kind of blocker. Artificial lack of intelligence strikes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [@RegDwigнt's tip](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6970/how-can-i-link-to-a-result-in-the-coca-corpus#comment26183_6970) about registering an account, I posted [a step-by-step guide to sharing COCA links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79855/97102) over on [Webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).